# Remove plastic film from the outside of a metal door?

Tags: doors, removal, plastic

I forgot to remove the plastic protective film from the outside of a metal door. The door is white prime/painted. I was able to remove the film from the inside of the door, but the outside is baked on and cracked. I have tried using a metal paint scraper, but the plastic is very resistant to that. I have tried soaking it in water, spraying JigALoo, and now GoofOff.

Should I try ammonia or a citrus cleaner or something else?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If Goof-Off isn't doing it, I'm thinking your best bet is to sand it and re-prime it.

Comment: I am hoping to keep this as a last resort :(

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that nothing is going to penetrate the plastic to get at the adhesive, unless you use something that's going to actually melt the plastic (i.e. a strong gel-type paint stripper), which could also damage the window lite. I think sanding to bare metal is your best bet. Doesn't take long with a random orbital sander.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to put it in the sun to warm it up. Spray it with WD-40 and let sit for about an hour. Get a non-scratch plastic scraper and have at it!

Answer (score 1):

I used Simple Green ( a degreaser). I soaked it overnight then next day put a fresh batch and scrubbed it with a pot scrub(wire mesh type). With one brush I was able to get it off...my door looks great...

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing -- I haven't done it yet it yet, but I believe Acetone will remove the plastic film -- it sure melts regular plastic.

Take a look at http://www.woodgrain.com/questions/faq/faq.html

They suggest a acetone based solvent to remove the plastic film.

Comment: Greg - Note that the window lite frame is plastic. I would hesitate to use Acetone because you'll risk damaging the window frame.

Comment: It'll also eat the primer off the door...

Answer (score 0):

I have also left my cromodeck door with its protective plastics on. The plastic film got baked in the angry Namibian summer sun until it was so brittle that it looks just like the pic above.

Normal household ammonia will put a smile on your face with zero scratches. Try it.